# How to use a C++ class in a QML component

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to design an application on a [QML component which embeds one C++ class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html). 
My class is the following :

```
class Fleche : public QQuickPaintedItem   // Fleche = arrow
{
public :
    Fleche();
    ~Fleche();

protected :
    QPainterPath arrow;
private :
    void paint(QPainter *painter){
        // Draw

        arrow.moveTo(50,50);
        arrow.lineTo(0,0);
        arrow.cubicTo(20,100/3,20,2*100/3,0,100);
        arrow.closeSubpath();

        // Paint

        QLinearGradient gradient(0, 0, 0, 100);
        gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt::white);
        gradient.setColorAt(1.0, Qt::darkBlue);
        QBrush fill(gradient);
        painter->setBrush(fill);
        painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        painter->drawPath(arrow);
    }

};
```

This item should be implemented 4 times in my QML code, and needs to be rotated, animated and resizeable.
I guess I have to use [updatePaintNode()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#updatePaintNode) but as a designer ( at least not a coder), I have trouble mixing languages ...
The idea is to have in my QML code :

```
Fleche {
        id : arrowNumberX // X is from 0 to 3
        width : 0.1 * parent.width
        height : 0.15 * parent.height
        z : 1
        rotation : X * 90
        MouseArea{ /.../}
        SequentialAnimation{/.../}
    }
```

Any example or help on how to implement my object in my QML application would help me a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least 3 ways to implement your own QML item (ordered from faster to slower).

1. [C++] Create class derived from  `QQuickItem` and override
       [QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#updatePaintNode)
2. [C++] Create class derived from `QQuickPaintedItem` and override
   [QQuickPaintedItem::paint()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html#paint)
3. [QML] Create Canvas-based item (see @Jérémy Mrgt's answer)

Comment: I have two questions :
1) Why is the QQuickItem class faster than the QQuickPaintedItem class ? Isn't the last one a child of the first one ?
2) I intend of course to use C++ code, but how do I use it in my QML code ?
Ps : I'm new on this forum I have no idea if I should ask question in the comment part, sorry if I shouldn't !

Comment: 1st way uses OpenGL while 2nd one use QPainter ie. first the item painted using QPainter and then this image painted as OpenGL texture in scene graph. Example you can found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/qml/6509/creating-custom-elements-in-c/22330/creating-custom-elements-in-c#t=201706131403549080664)

Answer (score 0):

Better idea for this, is to use Canvas - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-canvas-example.html, you will get smaller and cleaner code.

You can create new component called Fleche.qml, and use it wherever you want (rotated, animated and resizeable, ...)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's smaller and cleaner because it is greedier ! Or I'm developing HCI for embedded devices. I have very few power avalaible, and avoiding Javascript (QML) code to draw it needed. But trust me, if I could use Canvas item, i would. Thank you for answering and this example though !